# How to make objects follow the location of bones without rotation

Tags: animation, mesh, objects, armature, bones

[image]

I want to make the lights move with the bones so when I animate they follow, I tried using copy location but it doesn't work with bones (at least for me), I tried parenting the lights to the bones, but that parents the rotation too

Comment: pls provide blend file so we can check it out. thx.

Comment: pls use https://blend-exchange.com/ to share files. I couldn't access yours because i am working on a mac and that google extension is only available for windows.

Comment: The max limit is 30mb and it's about 44mb as a .blend file, what file format should I use, I tried obj and fbx but it doesn't export everything

Comment: Hello, @INeed..  You should make a minimal 'toy' example of your problem for others to look at, anyway.. less for them to hunt through. (Less for you, too, it might help you with your own debugging)

Comment: The only things in the file were the model and the lights, I'm not sure if I understand

Comment: I believe they mean to say you could in future try making a completely new file with only the most simple and necessary parts in place for anyone trying to help to use, it would make tinkering with it go a lot faster without needing to sort through hundreds of other unnecessary objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have a light object follow along with the location and position of an individual bone in an armature, you can utilize the "Child Of" Constraint.

Go to the constraint panel of your light source object, add the constraint, and then select the armature, then underneath, select the individual bone you want. Now just make sure you deselect X, Y, and Z for the rotation. This will make sure that your object doesn't get affected by that anymore.

Lastly you'll just need to use the "Set Inverse" button to make sure the object is in the right spot. It may have been moved a bit by the constraint. But you should be good after that.

[image]